# Dynamic change of content better ways. AngularJS 1.6

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, interpolation

I have REST service that gives some information for banner. I want to use this information for dynamic change of slider on main page.

So I simply use $http.get to get data, and then interpolation, with some additional ng-if's to check, if there is specific data, to displaying or not some elements.

```
<div class="main-block" ng-if="locale==='ru'">
            <div ng-repeat="slider in restData.result" ng-class="{'active':$first}" class="slide {{ slider.location }}" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{ slider.url.url }})'}">

                <div class="content-block">

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="right-block">
                            <h2>{{ slider.text1 }}</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div ng-if="slider.text2 || slider.text3 || slider.text4 || slider.text5" class="offer-block" ng-style="{'background':'rgba({{ slider.color }},0.6)'}">
                            <div class="offer-block__country">{{ slider.text2 }}</div>
                            <div class="offer-block__name">
                                {{ slider.text3 }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="offer-block__days">
                                {{ slider.text4 }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="offer-block__date">
                                {{ slider.text5 }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <a ng-if="slider.link" ui-sref="shell.tourShow({url:'{{ slider.link }}'})" class="orange-btn">
                            Подробнее
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But I feel like there must be better way to work with such type of data manipulation, more readable and understandable. Can you please help to find one, or give a little example, how to do it better.

Comment: create a directive and separate your html into directive template/templateUrl

Comment: @BimalDas I thought about this, but, as I can see it, it will only lead to more complexity, cause code I've provided it's like 80% of overal code in html file. But thank you, I will try to google more, and change it as you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is relatively good already, the only thing I would change is not to directly map to `ng-repeat="slider in restData.result"`

but rather create a `$scope` variable like

```
$scope.sliders = {};

// in rest request update the local variable with most recent data
// and then use ng-repeat="slider in sliders"
```